# Как в Yii2 вывести поля XML в gridview без БД?

Tags: yii2

Как сделать без переноса в базу xml файл?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1. Конвертировать XML в массив и использовать в качестве провайдера данных [yii\data\ArrayDataProvider](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider)

```
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;

$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name 1', ...],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name 2', ...],
    ...
    ['id' => 100, 'name' => 'name 100', ...],
];

$provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $data,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['id', 'name'],
    ],
]);
```

Вариант 2. Конвертировать XML в Json и использовать плагин для построение сетки, например [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Не получается создать массив

Comment: '$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name 1', ...],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'name 2', ...],
    ...
    ['id' => 100, 'name' => 'name 100', ...],
];
'

Comment: Ошибку выдает$image = simplexml_load_file("categories.xml");

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($image);

Comment: Цель - получить навзание элемента и его значение для массива : id name - названия